# Getting menu to be center of page with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This might be a silly question, but I'm still struggling with it. I've created a page and I would like to make the menu center. I used the offset but that pushes the menu to the center and it makes the page able to scroll to the side.

My html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-lg-offset-2">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main_menu" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: So did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

### Two ways to do this:

1. simply to add the css rule `text-align:center;` to your unordered list.

**Example CSS**

```
.center
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

2. Use the bootstrap class `text-center`

> Both do the same thing although as you are already using Bootstrap id
>   go with option 2.

---

Your updated code snippet (example)

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main_menu" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <!-- center and text-center classes added to '<ul>' element !-->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav center text-center">
              <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to remove the `col-lg-offset-2` so that it is centered on full screen. @MasterYoda

Comment: Ah, didnt notice that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text-center` in your class attribute. Its already built into bootstrap.

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main_menu" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                                <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```